# Idiomatic English expressions for "dead tired", "soaking drunk", "full packed"

Tags: idioms, adjectives

I have a question about using pairs of adjectives in everyday English speech.

Italian uses pairs of adjectives to emphasize a quality and some idiomatic and colloquial expressions are commonly accepted:

- *stanco morto*, literally "dead tired"
- *ubriaco fradicio*, literally "soaking drunk"
- *pieno zeppo*, literally "full packed"

Are the above expressions idiomatic English? If not, what are the equivalent English expressions for extremely great tiredness, extreme drunkenness, and extremely great fullness (such as after eating a lot)?

Comment: "Dead tired", "stinking drunk", &"stuffed" & "[stuffed to the gills](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_stuffed_to_the_gills_mean)" are all English idioms.

Comment: @Bill, do you think I should use the article in the first sentence before the word "use"? Or, is it more appropriate to avoid the problem using "using" in place of "the use"?

Comment: I'd write the sentence this way: _I have a question about using pairs of adjectives in everyday English speech_. If you use the "_regarding **use of** pairs of adjectives_" structure, I would definitely use the definite article: "_regarding **the use of** pairs of adjectives_".

Comment: @Bill, thank you. I edited the question to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: It seems to me that when used in this way, the first adjective in the pair becomes an adverb, as it's describing or further qualifying the second adjective. Not super relevant; just a thought.

Comment: @KenB: If it modifies the adjective, you can say that _it **functions** as an adverb in this compound adjective_, just as the noun _dog_ in the compound noun _dogsled_ functions as an adjective. Neither word changes part of speech, however, only function. This may simply be one theoretical perspective on lexical items. The philosophical question here is akin to _If you say one stupid thing in your life, can I call you **stupid** forever?_ [You can replace _stupid_ with any positive or negative descriptor (eg, _racist, sexist, intelligent_, etc) & the question is still valid.]

Comment: @BillFranke You make some good points there. I like that terminology ("*functions as* an adverb"). I don't know where I stand philosophically on the issue, since, for example, "*dead* tired" answers the question "*How* tired?", and it feels more accurate (to me) to say that "dead" is being given a new definition, meaning "completely or totally", that is clearly adverbial. (Is that a word? Adverbial?)

Comment: @Bill Franke: Agreed about including the article. We're well in the majority on this one. In Google Books, ["question regarding use of"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22question+regarding+use+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), 1920 hits - [question regarding **the** use of](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22question+regarding+the+use+of%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), 30,200 hits.

Comment: @KenB: When and **only when** it quacks adverbially, [it is an adverb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/). The category applies to its *function in context*, not to the word itself.

Comment: @ Carlo: I'm not going to post an answer, but I'll just point out that *blind drunk* is four times more common in Google Books than *stinking drunk*, and ***dead** drunk* is four times more common than *blind drunk*.

Answer (score 1):

"Dead tired" is a common idiom in English. "Soaking drunk" is not so common but is widely understood. We don't say "full packed", we say "packed full".

I find it amusing that you picked three Italian idioms that all translate nicely to English idioms. I suspect that is just luck and not a sign that you can do that in general.

Comment: You're certainly right that [soaking drunk](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22soaking+drunk%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is "not so common"!. Of 41 instances in Google Books there, most of them seem to be references to the fact that it's a literal translation of an Italian expression! By way of comparison, GB claims to have over 10,000 instances of [stinking drunk](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22stinking+drunk%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and 40,000 of [blind drunk](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22blind+drunk%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).